# make progress bar increse by time

Tags: timer, progress

i visit many pages but my question is different.
i made a code for progress bar based on time, i want to use it as file uploading, in this time i can not use ajax so i force to use it.

html :

```
<!--Progress Bar-->
<div class="publisher-hidden-option">
    <div id="progress">
        <span id="percent">0%</span>
        <div class="progress">
            <div id="bar" class="progress-bar active"></div> 
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript :

```
var ithis = 0;
var counterBackthis = setInterval(function(){
  ithis++;
  if (ithis < 100.5){
    $('#bar').css('width', ithis+'%');
    $('#percent').text(ithis+'%');
    //console.log(counterBackthis);
    //console.log(ithis);
  } else {
    clearInterval(counterBackthis);
  }
}, 2000);
```

the problem i here when upload finished i do :

```
$('#bar').css('width','100%');
$('#percent').text('100%');
clearInterval(counterBackthis);
```

but clears a timer  didn't work ! these script are in different function !
plese help me how can i fix this !

Answer (score 0):

it was easy, i put my answer here, i should remove var before of counterBackthis.